# Using document.ready in a single page application

Tags: jquery, single-page-application, document-ready

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) and I have some JS code with `$(document).ready(function(){...`. How can I make sure this function starts when a user browses another page and comes back because it doesn't work.

I don't know any jQuery which is why I need this kind of short way if there is any.

Comment: This might be an unpopular opinion but i highly suggest your look into actual SPA frameworks.( Angular, React, Vue, etc. ) Jquery isn't one of them.

Comment: Can you give some more information about what SPA framework you are using?

Comment: Hey! Have you tried to do a `console.log('Hello!')` by any chance to see if it isn't actually firing? Can we get some code examples?

Comment: `document.ready` will fire the first time the user visits the site. If you're using an SPA structure then it doesn't matter what page they visit after that as document.ready has already fired, you just need to use the appropriate callbacks after dynamically loading the content. As @Nicolas states though, you'd be far better off using an SPA framework instead of creating your own, especially if you're not familiar with JS, let alone jQuery.

Comment: you understood my problem Rory. So is there not a way that I can fire this function( which originaly fires when document ready) whenever user visits particular page?. I use vue I know it enough to use functions or hooks but i can not understand jquery code, that will be too much time consuming for me. Anyways thank you all for your answers

Comment: for example how would I transform this to plain JS code $(document).ready(function(){
  var mouseX, mouseY;
  var ww = $( window ).width();
  var wh = $( window ).height();
  var traX, traY;
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    traX = ((4 * mouseX) / 570) + 40;
    traY = ((4 * mouseY) / 570) + 50;
    console.log(traX);
    $(".title").css({"background-position": traX + "%" + traY + "%"});
    wh
    ww
  });
});